# Flutter: How to call function of Home button (home button default of Android)?

Tags: flutter

I have a button on the View and how to call function of Home button in onClick function of button?
Code example:

```
InkWell(
   onTap: () {
     //function of home button
 },)
```

Comment: You want to click on home button and jump to home widget?

Comment: I want to click on button to do the same as home button default of Android

Comment: because of this help to close the app but it doesn't restart the app when i come back :v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/move_to_background

Meaning your code could be something like this:

```
InkWell(
   onTap: () {
     MoveToBackground.moveTaskToBack();
   },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to achieve you need a background notifier because the home button sends app to background. There is a package called flutter_fgbg which can help you - [click here pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fgbg). Then you can proceed to stream background events, eg:

```
import 'package:flutter_fgbg/flutter_fgbg.dart';

StreamSubscription<FGBGType> subscription;

...
// in initState
subscription = FGBGEvents.stream.listen((event) {
if (event == FGBGType.foreground){

//if its come back to foreground, then restart your app

} else {

//if its gone to background

}
  
});

// in dispose
subscription.cancel();
```

For more assistance, you can check this link, for visual aid in solving problems [Mufungo Geeks YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/c/MufungoGeeks)